# In ant, how can I use replace to remove <link> tag?

Tags: ant, replace

I'm trying to eliminate a  tag in index.html, but with the following I am getting this error:

```
<replace file="${build.dir}/${app.page.name}" token='<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/AMC-all.css"/>' value=""/>

The value of attribute "token" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves it:

```
<fileset id="html.fileset"
    dir="${build.dir}"
    includes="${app.page.name}"/>

<replaceregexp replace="" flags="g"
    match='\&lt;\s*link\s*rel="stylesheet"\s*href=".*-all.css"\/\&gt;'>
    <fileset refid="html.fileset"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution without regular expression:

```
<replace dir="${out.dir}" encoding="utf8">
    <replacetoken><![CDATA[//<debug>]]></replacetoken>
    <replacevalue><![CDATA[/*<debug>]]></replacevalue>
</replace>
```